# Inheritance Example in java

Tags: java, inheritance

In the example below :

```
class Parent{
    void fun() {
        System.out.println("Parent class");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        Child ch = new Child();
        ch.fun();
    }
}
```

inheritance example,while instantiating object,we can create an object as `Parent ch = new Child();` which is valid but why can't we have something like this `Child ch = new Parent();`
           Thanks in advance.

Comment: every Child is a Parent, not every Parent is a Child. if you had chosen your classnames in a more logical way, it might have been more clear that way.

Comment: `Parent ch = new Child();` is called polymorphism, used to call the proper implementation at runtime, what you try to do has no sense

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Actually it's vice versa - a `Child` is a `Parent` and `Parent` is not a `Child`

Comment: let's simplify it... `class Apple extends Fruit` - every apple is a fruit, but not every fruit is an apple.

Comment: In your inheritance, a `Child` is a `Parent`, but a `Parent` is not a `Child`

Answer (score 1):

`Child ch = new Parent()` is invalid because not every `Parent` is a `Child`. 
Suppose you had a third class:

```
class AnotherChild extends Parent {int age = 2;}
```

The following would also be valid:

```
Parent otherChild = new AnotherChild();
```

If `Cild child = new Parent()` were to be made valid, then for the same reason

```
Child child = new AnotherChild()
```

**Would** also have to be made valid because `AnotherChild` **is a** `Parent`.

Now clearly, that is problematic, because `Child` is different from `AnotherChild`.

This example is chosen to make it obvious, but even a simple `Parent` object (`new Parent()`) is not a `Child` instance, because it wasn't instantiated with the `Child` class or any of its sub-classes.

All this is compile-time type checks, which ensures code safety and object/variable compatibility. One can use allowed casts to go around the problem, but if runtime objects are in fact of incompatible types, the execution would still fail.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have `class Child extends Parent{`. This means that a `Child` is a `Parent` but `Parent` is not a `Child`. `Parent` is the more generic parent class (Ironic) and `Child` is the more specific sub class. So you can do something like this:

```
 Parent ch = new Child();
```

Because you are declaring the generic `Parent` object, and then instantiating it as a `Child` object. However you cannot do:

```
Child ch = new Parent();
```

Because you cannot declare it as the more specific `Child` object and then instantiate it as the less specific `Parent` object